# Clicking a div that opens a corresponding div

Tags: php, jquery

I am dynamically creating a div class for a set of divs.  The class corresponds with the class of another set of divs (also dynamically generated).  I gave them the same class so as to be able to click on the div that displays by default and have the corresponding div appear (which is not displayed by default).  The setup would be something like this with divs 'foo' being displayed and 'bar' being hidden

```
<div id="foo" class="one">1</div>
<div id="foo" class="two">2</div>
<div id="foo" class="three">3</div>

<div id="bar" class="one">One</div>
<div id="bar" class="two">Two</div>
<div id="bar" class="three">Three</div>
```

I dont know how to put this in jQuery.  I know it is going to be a click function, I'm just not sure how to grab a class where I'm not sure what the value is.  Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same id.  It's unlikely anything will work correctly until that's fixed.

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<div  class="foo one">1</div>
<div  class="foo two">2</div>
<div  class="foo three">3</div>

<div class="bar one">One</div>
<div class="bar two">Two</div>
<div class="bar three">Three</div>
```

Then when someone clicks on a `foo` div:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.foo", function(){
    $("div.foo:hidden:first").show();
});
```

Of course that obviates the need for the `one` `two` and `three` classes.  Did you want something like this:

```
<div  class="foo foo1">1</div>
<div  class="foo foo2">2</div>
<div  class="foo foo3">3</div>

var nextToShow = 1;

$(document).on("click", "div.foo", function(){
    $("div.foo" + nextToShow++).show();
});
```

Comment: with the same class you mean? if I changed the corresponding classes to Corone, Cortwo, Corthree, etc...would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you must give different ids to your divs because each id given to html elements must be unique. However once fixed, in jQuery you could access and assign click event to dives by `class` names like this:

```
$(".one, .two, .three").click(function(e){
    alert("hello");
});
```

or you could collect divs by `id` like this:

```
$("#foo, #bar").click(function(e){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write it like

```
<div id="foo_1" class="foo one">1</div>
<div id="foo_2" class="foo two">2</div>
<div id="foo_3" class="foo three">3</div>

<div id="bar_1" class="bar one">One</div>
<div id="bar_2" class="bar two">Two</div>
<div id="bar_3" class="bar three">Three</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.foo').live('click',function(){
   $('.bar').hide();
   var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
   for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
       if(classes[i] != 'foo'){
            $('.bar.'+class[i]).show();
       }
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think this one is close to what Im looking for.  The issue is that the id is what is helping keep the element styled the way I wanted it (which is the reason I needed them all the same).  I was trying to use the class as the common element...

Comment: as others said, ID has to be unique. just change your CSS form #bar to div.bar  and #foo to div.foo in your CSS and you are all set.

Comment: If you do decide to go this way, note that `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7; check out the `.on()` documentation which will steer you in the right direction to update it, though.